# Parallax.js on HTML body tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use Parallax.js on the html `body` tag.

https://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/
https://github.com/pixelcog/parallax.js/

I added jQuery, path to Parallax, and data parameters to the body, but it doesn't show.

I've tried placing the js in head and footer. Where I am going wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/kyttft92/

```
<body data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="http://i.imgur.com/yXmsCmA.jpg">
  <ul>
    <li>parallax</li>
    <li>parallax</li>
    <li>parallax</li>
    <li>parallax</li>
    <li>parallax</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Adding a class to `body` and calling manually with jQuery also has no effect.

`$('.parallax-window').parallax({imageSrc: 'http://i.imgur.com/yXmsCmA.jpg'});`

Here is also a cdnjs file:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parallax.js/1.4.2/parallax.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, your error has nothing to do with not loading resources or syntax errors, but with not reading the documentation and trying to use it in ways it was not designed for:

From [`Under The Hood`](https://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/#underthehood):

> What parallax.js will do is create a fixed-position element for each parallax image at the start of the document’s body. This mirror element will sit behind the other elements and match the position and dimensions of its target object.

That basically means you can't parallax `<body>`, because it's used as a container for the effect. (It will try to create a mirror of `<body>` and place it as a child of `<body>`. Does that make any sense?).

Just place it all in a container, for the sole purpose of using `parallax.js`

---

**Additional note:** According to Matt's comment, `parallax.js` currently requires jQuery 2.2.4 or below in order to work properly.

Comment: I think this and the following are the lines that makes it fail when used as body - a body can't have a child body element... https://github.com/pixelcog/parallax.js/blob/master/parallax.js#L116

Comment: @baao indeed. But I think without that line it won't work as intended. After all, the purpose here is to have a working parallax, is it not?

Comment: It is working now. There was another problem preventing the images from showing. It only works with jQuery 2.2.4 and below https://jsfiddle.net/xj9qcy9z/

Comment: Thanks. I'll update the answer (it might be useful to others, too).